# i want to show the message from start date to end date which is set on input field?

Tags: angular

Can I use `ngOnChange`

```html
<div>
  <label for="start">Start date:</label>
  <input type="time" name="starts" [(ngModel)]="starts">
  <label for="start">End date: </label>
  <input type="time" name="end" [(ngModel)]="ends">
  <button type="submit" (click)="">submit </button>
</div>
```

want show below msg

```html
<div> "some msgs" </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain your question? You said you want to show the start, and end dates on the input field. But show where?

Comment: i want to show the message from start date to end date which is set on input field? dont see code just tell me how can i??plz @wentjun

Comment: any message or value

Comment: @TarunKumar Do you mean something like `<div>From: {{starts}} To: {{ends}}</div>`?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually pretty simple.

Basically, the line of code with `<div *ngIf="starts && ends">{{ starts + '-' + ends }}</div>` will only show if the models `starts` and `ends` contain a value (meaning, they are not null, undefined, or empty strings). Therefore, that message will only show once both input boxes are filled.

you can do something like this:

```
<div>
  <label for="start">Start date:</label>
  <input type="time" name="starts" [(ngModel)]="starts">
  <label for="start">End date: </label>
  <input type="time" name="end" [(ngModel)]="ends">
  <div *ngIf="starts && !ends">some msgs</div>
  <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">submit </button>
</div>
```

Here is a simple [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-14x8er?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: it doesnt work.. the msg still appears when end date comes @wentjun

Comment: @TarunKumar wait.. what is the condition for the message to appear/hide? Ok I think I get it.. You want that message to appear when `starts` is filled, but when the `ends` is filled, it will disppear?